# Visualizing multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, keen-io

Attempting to hookup Keen javascript visualizer to two datasets, hitting errors in everything I've tried.

Tried using multi-analysis to get the response, this works but doesn't plug into the chart.

https://keen.io/docs/api/#multi-analysis

Also tried running separate queries and use `client.run` on keen analysis client. Each query runs fine separately but when run together produces and error in the chart regarding `timeframe.start`.

https://keen.io/docs/visualize/common-chart-examples/#area-step-chart-with-multiple-results

Tools:

```
"keen-analysis": "^3.4.0",
"keen-dataviz": "^3.5.3",
"keen-tracking": "^4.3.1",
```

Chart setup

```
const matchBreakdown = new keenDataviz({
  container: "#match-breakdown",
  type: "area-step",
  title: "Match Breakdown (last 2 months)",
  showLoadingSpinner: true
});
```

Multi-analysis attempt:

```
client
  .query("multi_analysis", {
    event_collection: "kitchen.matches",
    analyses: {
      "total_matches": {
        analysis_type: "count",
        filters: [
          {"operator":"eq","property_name":"environment","property_value":"production"}
        ]
      },
      "bad_matches": {
        analysis_type: "count",
        filters: [
          {"operator":"eq","property_name":"environment","property_value":"production"},
          {"operator":"eq","property_name":"match_count","property_value":0}
        ]
      }
    },
    timezone: "US/Mountain",
    group_by: ["date"],
    order_by: ["date"],
    timeframe: "this_60_days"
  })
  .then(res => {
    matchBreakdown.render(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Source data is missing a component at (0,1)!
    matchBreakdown.message(err.message);
  });
```

Multiple queries attempt:

```
const allMatches = client
  .query("count", {
    event_collection: "kitchen.matches",
    filters: [{"operator":"eq","property_name":"environment","property_value":"production"}],
    group_by: ["date"],
    order_by: ["date"],
    timezone: "US/Mountain",
    timeframe: "this_2_months"
  });

const badMatches = client
  .query("count", {
    event_collection: "kitchen.matches",
    filters: [
      {"operator":"eq","property_name":"environment","property_value":"production"},
      {"operator":"eq","property_name":"match_count","property_value":0}
    ],
    group_by: ["date"],
    order_by: ["date"],
    timezone: "US/Mountain",
    timeframe: "this_2_months"
  });

client
  .run([allMatches, badMatches])
  .then(res => {
    matchBreakdown.render(res);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
    matchBreakdown.message(error.message);
  });
```

Note that this works:

```
client.run([badMatches]).then(res => {
  matchBreakdown.render(res);
});

// Or this

client.run([allMatches]).then(res => {
  matchBreakdown.render(res);
});
```

The examples give no further information on how to format response data, it seems like it should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was checking Your problem and unfornatelly `filters` are not working for multianalysis, also You cannot use `group_by` while running few queries `.run([allMatches, badMatches])`

I prepared example with other solution based on this: `https://jsfiddle.net/a2fvmk1h/`

Instead of `group_by` You can use `interval` to receive similar results. Here is an example for You: `https://jsfiddle.net/dariuszlacheta/h0x6mvan/14/`
The fact that You are using the same queries `count` on the same `event collection` is causing problems with naming results so You have to do one trick. You need to change at least one 'analysis_type' for the results because otherwise data will be overwrite: `res[1].query.analysis_type = 'games';`

I dont have access to Your data but I guess this is how it will look with Your code:

```
const allMatches = client
  .query("count", {
    event_collection: "kitchen.matches",
    filters: [
      {
         "operator":"eq",
         "property_name":"environment",
         "property_value":"production"
      }
    ],
    interval: "daily"
    timezone: "US/Mountain",
    timeframe: "this_2_months"
  });

const badMatches = client
  .query("count", {
    event_collection: "kitchen.matches",
    filters: [
      {
         "operator":"eq",
         "property_name":"environment",
         "property_value":"production"
      },
      {
         "operator":"eq",
         "property_name":"match_count",
         "property_value":0
      }
    ],
    interval: "daily"
    timezone: "US/Mountain",
    timeframe: "this_2_months"
  });

client
  .run([allMatches, badMatches])
  .then(res => {
    res[1].query.analysis_type = 'badMatches';
    matchBreakdown.render(res);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
    matchBreakdown.message(error.message);
  });
```

I will try solve this issue with overwriting query names when two or more the same queries are used in `.run([])`

Comment: Thanks! I added `group_by` because I backfilled data so I don't think `interval` was working correctly (even though I overwrote `keen.timestamp`). I'm not certain on this so I'll try it out.

Comment: Let me know if this is working somehow for Your case :)